# cannot get socket.io after changing application url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

There are lots of questions around this topic here, most of which are irrelevant because I'm using express 4.16.4 and socket.io 2.2.0.
Second, because my example already works on both localhost and remote hosting.

On my remote hosted server I can create a nodejs application by providing three options:

- application root
- application URL
- application startup file

My barebone example application is installed in `/test`, see file structure:

```
/test
  /node_modules
    /lots of folders
  index.html
  index.js
  package.json
/domains/
  /mydomain.com
    /public_html
      index.html
```

Everything works fine when I go to `mydomain.com` and my console prints `tx received!` with the following parameters:

- application root = `'test'`
- application URL = `''`
- application startup file = `'index.js'`

Now I want the application to be accessible on `mydomain.com/test` instead.
But when I change my application URL from `''` to `'test'`, `io` is undefined because I cannot get the file `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.
I still get the index file served by express because I also change 
`app.get("/",` to `app.get("/test",`

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(8000);
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var io = socketIO(server);

app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/index.html" );
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('tx');
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();
      socket.on('tx', function () {
        console.log('tx received!');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    TEST
  </body>
</html>
```

With Express, I can use app.use() succesfully to serve static files in `__dirname` when `/test` is requested.

The problem is socket.io does some magic to make a connection and I don't know if there is a socket.io equivalent of `app.use`.

Tnx for the long read and any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I figured out a solution:

To change the application url, the socket.io server path needs to be changed as well, see [the server docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server).

Server side `index.js`: `var io = socketIO(server, {path: '/test/socket.io'});`

Client side `index.html`: `<script src="/test/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` and connect to new url `var socket = io.connect({path: "/test/socket.io"});`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **socket.use()** which registers a middleware, which is a function that gets executed for every incoming Packet receives.
For example

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.use((packet, next) => {
    if (packet.doge === true) return next();
    next(new Error('Not a doge error'));
  });
});
```

For this particular question you can just take you socketio importing code and the other code to a separate js file which will export the io object, so that you can referrer the code in every html file that you are chaining to by importing the scripts.

Comment: How can I then use this middleware to redirect the request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`?

Comment: So I go to `mydomain.com/test`, I get the index.html, which in turn tries to load `mydomain.com/test/socket.io/socket.io.js` which is not available. You are suggesting that instead of serving the index.html, I serve some kind of js script using `socket.use()` middleware which already has imported io?

Comment: I have no idea how to approach this problem.